# Understanding code sbuf_remove(sbuf_t *sp) from book CSAPP? : issue for location of P(&sp->items)

Tags: c, concurrency

As reading the book < Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective > and in the chapter of Concurrent Programming, I saw a this function:

```
int sbuf_remove(sbuf_t *sp){
   int item;     '
   P(&sp->items);
   P(&sp->mutex);
   if (++sp->front >= sp->n)
      sp-> front = 0;
   item = sp->buf[sp->front]
   V(&sp->mutex);
   V(&sp->slots);
   return item;
}
```

After reading the code, I think some problematic situation.

Problematic Situation's conditions :

1. &sp->items = 1 ,
2. two consumers reach at P(&sp->items) code at same time (before none of them reach to P(&sp->mutex);

In this situation, I think two consumers should have race and make problem.

(After one consumer_1 finish sbuf_remove, items become 0 but consumer_2 already pass P(&sp->items) code. Therefore consumer_2 fail to get correct item and return unexpectable value.)

I am wondering why package developer did not use mutex's lock code before enter items, slots semasphore.

I mean the code should be changed like this. Isn't it more safe than original code?

```
P(&sp->mutex);
P(&sp->items);
if (++sp->front >= sp->n)
   sp-> front = 0;
item = sp->buf[sp->front]
V(&sp->slots);
V(&sp->mutex);
```

Comment: What do `P()` and `V()` do?

Comment: 'void P(sem_t *s)' is a wrapper function for  sem_wait and 'void V(sem_t *s) is a wrapper function for sem_post. (Which are function in <semaphore.h>

Comment: The details are on the csapp book.

Comment: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/ics3/code/src/csapp.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `sem_wait` waits until the semaphore is nonzero before atomically decrementing it.  So if two consumers reach `P(&sp->items)` at the same time with `sp->items==1`, one of them will decrement `items` and go on to remove the last item.  The other will see that `items == 0` and block until some producer adds an item.  They cannot both pass `P(&sp->items)`. I don't see any race here.

On the other hand your "more safe" suggestion is a little too safe.  Suppose a consumer enters `sbuf_remove` when the queue is empty, so `sp->items == 0`.  It takes the mutex and then blocks (still holding the mutex!) waiting for `sp->items` to become positive, which will only happen when a producer adds an item.  But in order to add an item to the queue, the producer presumably would need to take the mutex, which it can't do because the consumer holds it.  We thus have a classic deadlock.

Comment: I got it. I misunderstood about "at the same time". Thanks for your example about "too safe".